# VS2022 get Target Framework of Main executable from class library csproj

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

We need to obtain the TargetFramework of the Main executable assembly from a class library project's csproj file. This is so the class library can target net7.0-android. The below code fails with XmlDocument is not available for execution in an MSBuild property function.

How can we achieve what we are trying to do?

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <MainExecutableTargetFramework>$([System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new().Load("$($(MSBuildStartupDirectory))/$(AssemblyName).csproj").SelectSingleNode("/Project/PropertyGroup/TargetFramework").InnerText)</MainExecutableTargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(MainExecutableTargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-android' ">
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You have two different problems. First, you can't use `XmlDocument`. See ["Property functions"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022). Second, you need to set the value of `TargetFrameworks` in the evaluation phase. You could read the project file with the `XmlPeek` task but targets are not performed until the execution phase. Have you considered making the class library project multi-targeted?

Comment: @tech74 Hi, have you check my answer, does it be able to meet your requirement? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jonathan mentioned, there doesn't have a usage that you used in your property:

[Property function syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022#property-function-syntax)

only these categories:

> 1, String (instance) property functions
>
> 2, Static property functions
>
> 3, MSBuild property functions

Take a look of the static property functions, you could find that only the below is allowed:

**1, public static method or property of these system classes:**

```
System.Byte
System.Char
System.Convert
System.DateTime
System.DateTimeOffset (Available in MSBuild 17.3 and higher)
System.Decimal
System.Double
System.Enum
System.Guid
System.Int16
System.Int32
System.Int64
System.IO.Path
System.Math
System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation
System.UInt16
System.UInt32
System.UInt64
System.SByte
System.Single
System.String
System.StringComparer
System.TimeSpan
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
System.UriBuilder
System.Version
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper
```

**2, static methods and properties:**

```
System.Environment::CommandLine
System.Environment::ExpandEnvironmentVariables
System.Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable
System.Environment::GetEnvironmentVariables
System.Environment::GetFolderPath
System.Environment::GetLogicalDrives
System.Environment::Is64BitOperatingSystem
System.Environment::Is64BitProcess
System.Environment::MachineName
System.Environment::NewLine (Available in MSBuild 17.3 and higher)
System.Environment::OSVersion
System.Environment::ProcessorCount
System.Environment::StackTrace
System.Environment::SystemDirectory
System.Environment::SystemPageSize
System.Environment::TickCount
System.Environment::UserDomainName
System.Environment::UserInteractive
System.Environment::UserName
System.Environment::Version
System.Environment::WorkingSet
System.IO.Directory::GetDirectories
System.IO.Directory::GetFiles
System.IO.Directory::GetLastAccessTime
System.IO.Directory::GetLastWriteTime
System.IO.Directory::GetParent
System.IO.File::Exists
System.IO.File::GetAttributes
System.IO.File::GetCreationTime
System.IO.File::GetLastAccessTime
System.IO.File::GetLastWriteTime
System.IO.File::ReadAllText
```

So System.Xml.XmlDocument can't use in property.

These is a method for handling XML document, you could take a look of this:

[Read launchSettings.json values from MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76769232/6261890)